# Does anyone know what this regexp_replace do?

Tags: sql, regex, regexp-replace

I received this snippet from someone who doesn't work for my current company anymore, and I can't figure out what this regex do.

The objective for him was to scan through sql query strings and rearrange table info

`regexp_replace(query, ' ("*?)(analytics_internal|arr|bizops_analytics|cloud_api|cloud_backend_raw|data_science|eloqua|fb_ads|google_ads|information_schema|intricately|legacy_sfdc|marketing_analytics|ns__analytics_postprocessing|ns__global_write|product_analytics|raw_bing_ads|raw_cloud_api|raw_compass|raw_coveo|raw_eloqua|raw_g_search_console|raw_gainsight|raw_google_ads|raw_intercom|raw_linkedin_ads|raw_mightysignal|raw_realm|raw_sfdc|remodel_cloud|remodel_test|sales_analytics|sales_ops|sampledb|segment|sfdc|ts_analytics|university_platform_analytics|upstream_gainsight|usage|xform_cloud|xform_etl|xform_finance|xform_marketing|xform_reference|xform_sales|xform_tables)("*?)\.("*?)(.+?)("*?)(\s|$)', ' awsdatacatalog.$1$2$3.$4$5$6$7') as queryString`

Comment: Job security through obscurity. But in all seriousness it uses a few different capture groups and replaces whatever is matched with `awsdatacatalog.$1$2$3.$4$5$6$7` where the $num values are the matches from each respective capture group. It looks like the main idea is to prefix the matches with `awsdatacatalog.` My guess is it tries to create a new query that uses a `awsdatacatalog` db instead of the original.

Comment: Please send the code to thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 0):

The regex you've provided attempts to match any of the many provided strings in the second capture group and modify that part of the query to be prefixed with `awsdatacatalog.`. This is most likely an attempt to modify queries to occur on a new database, in particular a database named `awsdatacatalog`. For example, the consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "analytics_internal".foo.table
```

Your regex_replace should produce a new query that looks like

```sql
SELECT * FROM awsdatacatalog."analytics_internal".foo.table
```